# Bug: cannot change segment.bytes of Changelog Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Hello Folks we using statful microservices kafka streams and the restoration of these microservices take a lot of time, and some times all Microservices deployed in pods crach because the init take alot of time.  in order to reduce the restoration time we decide to change the segment size of changelog topic 1 GB to 100MB but in the log cleaner we don't see any more the compaction process and new .log files dont created when we go beyond 100MB, is like the older config of 1GB is already used by the changelog topic. kafkav 2.0.0

ex: -rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka 139884830 Nov 12 09:16 00000000000000000000.log

Comment: `we don't see any more the compaction process` -- maybe the log cleaner thread died? Check the broker logs. If might need to restart the broker to recover the log cleaner thread.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax thanks for you answer, I change the segment.bytes in the topic not in sever.properties-> log.segment.bytes and when I add  segment.bytes  to kafka topic or kafka changeLog topic this value should overwhrite the log.segment.bytes and I dont have to restart the broker, according to kafka doc if I restart the server I will create some troubles

Comment: Not sure about those details on the top of my head -- however, I believe a config change would only apply to new segments? Existing segments would not be split or merged.

Comment: thanks @MatthiasJ.Sax. you are right and we are agree the new conf value will be applied only to the new segments, but my issue is with the current segment.
I have a Kafka stream changelog topic created with the default segment size 1GB, when I put the segment bytes to 100MB, kafka does't create a new segment even if the current segment have more than 100MB. So we have the first segment with 1GB and after, kafka create the comming segments with the correct value 100MB (I am using kafka 2.0.1)

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax to resume with Kafka v2.0.1 Kafka not apply immediately the new segment.bytes value to the topic we need to wait for the current segment to reach 1GB after this new segments with the new value will be created, but with Kafka 0.10.0 the change is applied immediately, the current segment will be stopped and new segments with the new value will be created.

Comment: Maybe -- I would recommend to create a Jira ticket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2.0.1, the segment.bytes and segment.ms are only being applied to new segments. I had the same problem and I tested locally. So, you need to wait to have the active segment filled up (or expired).

In 2.3.0, this is not the case anymore. Active segments receive the config right away.